# How to bind a server certificate to a HttpListener SSL port on Linux .NET Core 2.0

Tags: linux, ssl, .net-core, httplistener

The .Net Core 2.0 Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netcore-2.0) for the HttpListner has a note stating that you can associate a server certificate with a port using the HttpCfg.exe program shipped with Windows Server 2003.

I'm looking for a way to bind a server certificate to a HttpListener port on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that for now because this feature (HTTPS support for unix) implementation is planned for 2.1.0 milestone. See [issue on github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14691)